# Plotting points in voronoi respective to x and y coords to join an additional coordinate

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working on plotting a voronoi point between two coordinates. So that the point aligns with respective to the `lower` and `upper` values in the dataframe.

Unfortunately, when I plot the data, it linearly increases by the value of the points. This then produces the following plot:

[image]

Here's the script that I used:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggvoronoi)
ggplot(voronoi_data, aes(x=lower, y=upper)) + stat_voronoi() +geom_point(aes(fit))

ggplot(voronoi_data, aes(x = lower, y = upper)) +
  stat_voronoi(
    geom = "path",
    color = 4,
    lwd = 0.7,
    linetype = 1
  ) + geom_point(aes(fit))
```

Some points do not lie within the voronoi diagram because they are either too large or too small. Therefore, I have thought of incrementing the `upper` and `lower` value by `fit`, and layering two voronoi over one another with two different colour schemes and then plotting the `fit` values (this is currently under process as I just had this idea.)

The update on the progress idea:

```
voronoi_1 <-
  mapply(function(a, b)
    a - b, voronoi_data$lower, voronoi_data$fit) %>% data.frame(lower_add =
                                                                  .)
voronoi_1 <-
  rbind(
    voronoi_1,
    mapply(function(a, b)
      a + b, voronoi_data$lower, voronoi_data$fit) %>% data.frame(lower_add =
                                                                    .)
  )

voronoi_2 <-
  mapply(function(a, b)
    a + b, voronoi_data$upper, voronoi_data$fit) %>% data.frame(upper_add =
                                                                  .)
voronoi_2 <-
  rbind(
    voronoi_2,
    mapply(function(a, b)
      a - b, voronoi_data$upper, voronoi_data$fit) %>% data.frame(upper_add =
                                                                    .)
  )

voronoi_3 <- rep(voronoi_data$fit, 2) %>% data.frame(fit = .)
voronoi_update <- cbind(voronoi_1, voronoi_2, voronoi_3)

ggplot(voronoi_data, aes(x = lower, y = upper)) +
  stat_voronoi(
    geom = "path",
    color = 4,
    lwd = 0.7,
    linetype = 1
  ) + geom_point(aes(fit), col = 'blue') + stat_voronoi(
    data = voronoi_update,
    aes(x = lower_add, y = upper_add),
    geom = "path",
    color = 2,
    lwd = 0.7,
    linetype = 1
  ) + geom_point(col = 'green') + geom_segment(aes(
    x = lower,
    y = upper,
    xend = fit,
    yend = fit
  ))
```

Update produces the following picture:

[image]

How can I get the `green-dots` to connect with the `blue-dots`?

reproducible data:

```
structure(list(lower = c(-50.231394143356, -56.2551026846824, 
28.4249214917657, -72.7725910398994, -81.2658846682781, 21.6407972918016, 
-6.38857800084765, -83.9469403037355, -7.49345446155375, -9.25035611734441
), upper = c(83.3536041213786, 63.9866816320508, 145.329559457229, 
48.0937531194102, 42.462115738722, 136.959651947817, 100.752432092854, 
40.2250494139988, 110.279218627158, 107.6295802627), fit = c(16.5611049890113, 
3.86578947368421, 86.8772404744972, -12.3394189602446, -19.4018844647781, 
79.3002246198091, 47.1819270460033, -21.8609454448684, 51.3928820828022, 
49.1896120726776)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L
))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your points aren't lying in the Voronoi is that you have put `aes(fit)` inside `geom_point`. This is interpreted as the x axis value for the points, which presumably isn't what you want:

```r
ggplot(voronoi_data, aes(x = lower, y = upper)) +
  stat_voronoi(
    geom = "path",
    color = 4,
    lwd = 0.7,
    linetype = 1
  ) + geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried this - this only seems to produce the points of `lower` relative to `upper`. I was interested in plotting the points from `fit` to see how far they were from `upper` and `lower`, but even after expanding the size of the diagram, they still fall far off because they're largely skewed to `+x` values. It doesn't look like an issue with the code anymore but largely the data I am working with. thank you for taking the opportunity to look into this!

Comment: I have updated my post as I had an additional idea from before - the plot from the update should attach the lines from the green dots to the blue dots, any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: I'm really struggling to understand what you are trying to achieve. What does the red voronoi represent in your above plot? Overlapping voronois are ugly and difficult to interpret, and it's not clear from your question what you are trying to show. Is there any chance you could edit your question to explain this a bit?

Comment: I have updated my question; the red voronoi is the addition/substraction of the upper/lower values. So it's a bigger voronoi that includes the values for `fit`. I am specifically overlaping these because they're in someway from the same coin. My updated approach want to know how I ca attach a line from the `green-dots` which are the points beloning to the blue voronoi to the `blue-dots` which is fit. These should match respectively.

Comment: But the red voronoi doesn't correspond to _either_ set of points. Also, you are still doing `aes(fit)`, which is putting `fit` on the x axis and `upper` on the y axis. Your segments are joining the green points to `fit` on the x axis and `fit` on the y axis too (whereas the `yend` should be `upper` if you want them to touch the green points.)